# looping logistic regressions through multiple dependent and independent variables in R

Tags: r, loops, logistic-regression

As with many, I'm sure this isn't a difficult answer but being new to R I have not been able to figure it out.

I have a dataset with roughly 100K cases that I am trying to run a series of logistic regressions that loops through various dependent and independent variables.

I'm not sure how to provide data here, but here's a sample:

```
Loc1  loc2  loc3  demo1  demo2  demo3  demo4  demo5  Outcome1  Outcome2
1     0     0     0      1      0      0      1      1         0
0     1     0     1      0      0      1      0      0         1
1     0     0     0      0      1      0      1      0         1
0     0     1     1      0      0      1      0      1         0
```

Basically, its a bunch of dummy variables that I'd like to run a bunch of regressions on like this:
glm(outcome ~ location * demographic variable)

where there are 4 outcome variables that will be predicted by each combination of 9 locations and 13 different demographic variables.

Again - I assume this isn't a difficult answer, but I've had difficulty figure out how to loop over multiple variables at the same time like this.
Thanks in advance.

Ok - let me try and clarify.
I primarily want to run the regressions grouped by location, so I'd see them all for location 1, then all for location 2, location 3, etc.

There are 9 different locations, 13 different demographic variables, and 4 different outcome variables.

I would want a loop that does something to this effect:

```
for(location):
    for(outcome):
        for(demographic):
           summary(glm(outcome ~ demographic * location))
```

I don't know how to add a sample dataset, but if someone lets me know I can add something more substantial than the 4 cases I put here.

Comment: please clarify your input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds all the combinations that are possible with that dataset, and then runs them through a loop to print and store the results. I must warn you that this is a terrible idea statistically, so this is just to show how the code would work. I'm assuming you didn't expect all the models to deliver meaningful results with such a toy dataset.

```
combos <- expand.grid( 
         locs = names(dat)[ grep("loc", names(dat), ignore.case=TRUE)], 
         demos = names(dat)[ grep("demo", names(dat),ignore.case=TRUE)]  )
res.list =list()
for (i in 1:3 ){
                form=as.formula(paste0("cbind(dat$Outcome1,dat$Outcome2) ~", 
                                         combos$locs[i], "+", combos$demos[i]));
                res.list[[1]] <- print( glm(form, data=dat, family="binomial") )}
```

Output

```
#--------
Call:  glm(formula = form, family = "binomial", data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Loc1        demo1  
  2.220e-16   -4.441e-16           NA  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
Null Deviance:      5.545 
Residual Deviance: 5.545    AIC: 9.545

Call:  glm(formula = form, family = "binomial", data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         loc2        demo1  
  4.960e-18   -3.913e+01    1.957e+01  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  1 Residual
Null Deviance:      5.545 
Residual Deviance: 2.773    AIC: 8.773

Call:  glm(formula = form, family = "binomial", data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         loc3        demo1  
  1.341e-16    3.913e+01   -1.957e+01  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  1 Residual
Null Deviance:      5.545 
Residual Deviance: 2.773    AIC: 8.773
```

Comment: just one doubt.... MikeD asked for glm(outcome ~ location * demographic variable) i.e. Loc * Demo, and your answer had "+":  form=as.formula(paste0("cbind(dat$Outcome1,dat$Outcome2) ~", 
                                         combos$locs[i], "+", combos$demos[i]));

Comment: Well, yours is one interpretation of the natural language phrase: "each combination of 9 locations and 13 different demographic variables". You would have produced only a single model. Mine is a different interpretation of that phrase, modulo that fact that we only had 3 and 5 to work with in the example. The aspect that I didn't think could be covered with the offered example what what was desired (and how to deliver) regarding the Outcomes.

Comment: Agree. Surely MikeD would take care of the rest :-)

Comment: I didn't figure out how to get your answer to work, but it did get me in the right direction, so a similar answer worked for me. Thanks

Comment: So you upvoted but didn't checkmark? No problem.

Comment: my bad man - forgot the checkmark.